# input value affecting brother unexpectedly

Tags: angular

I have the following code, using primeNg's InputNumber.

*EDIT: This is not PrimeNg related, as the bug persists even with a regular input.*

It has a very odd side affect, that when I add a value to the first input, it automatically shows in the next one too. It just shows in the input, without actually affecting the model behind.
This happens on others too, sometimes, if they have the same value as the next one.
Can anyone help me understand what is happening?

TS:

```
  get count(): number {
    return this._count;
  }

  set count(value: number) {
    this._count = value;
    if (this.means.length > value) {
      this.means = this.means.slice(0, value);
    }
    while (this.means.length < value) {
      this.means.push(0);
    }
  }

  private _count: number = 0;
  means: number[] = [];
```

HTML:

```
    <div *ngFor="let mean of means; let i=index">
      <label [for]="'mean'+i">Mean {{i}}</label>
      <p-inputNumber [id]="'mean'+i" [(ngModel)]="means[i]"></p-inputNumber>
    </div>
```

Stackblitz link: [sample with code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zyidax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Image with example:
What has happened is the first value has been inputed, and the next input automatically got the same value, but the model was not affected. The desire is to not have the second one show that false value
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10423#issuecomment-237123496).

According to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10423#issuecomment-236990566), the core problem is

> you're iterating the items you're editing and they are primitive values. ngFor can't keep track by identity because when the value changes from 1 to 3 (by editing) it becomes a different identity

so the solution is to use trackBy. By adding

```
  indexTracker(index: number, value: any): number {
    return index;
  }
```

to the TS file and adding

```
    <div *ngFor="let mean of means; let i=index; trackBy: indexTracker">
```

to the HTML file, the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

i changed means to an array object :

```
means: {title: string, value:number}[] = [];
```

and bind the ngModel like this;

```
<p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="mean.value"></p-inputNumber>
```

this works.

and also updated the other fields in html with title.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zyidax-dhzcr8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: while that does fix the bug, it leaves me saving extra data I have no need to store. 
Also, there is no meaning to a `for` in html if there is no matching id...

Comment: You can simply remove title field inside the object ...

Comment: It still means changing the data type unnecessarily. As I posted in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64783332/14492841) the issue was the trackBy